# GraphQL.js, Arguments on Subfield

Tags: json, express, graphql, graphql-js

I have set up a GraphQL database using GraphQL.js and Express that fetches the data from a hardcoded JSON-Object. My JSON-Object looks like this:

```
exports.store = {
"categories": 
 { ... },
"customers":
 { ... },
"vendors":
 { ... },
"items":
 { ... },
"products": 
 { ... },
}
```

With multiple entries for every category and subfields for every entry depending on the category. I have written resolvers for all the categories and can for example get the data for a specific customer by id.

What I want to do now is something similiar to a WHERE-Clause in SQL. An entry for products looks like this:

```
"1": {
             "id":1,
             "name":"Coconut",
             "category":{
                 "id":1,
                 "name":"Fruits"
             },
             "vendor":{
                 "id":32,
                 "name":"Exotic Fruits Company"
             }
         },
```

So now I would like to be able to do a query, that gives me all products  that have a certain vendor specified by it's id. Can I somehow reuse the resolvers I have already written for this? Is it even possible to have an argument on a subfield that specified which of it's parents are to be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you meant with `to have an argument on a subfield that specified which of it's parents are to be returned`.

I read you want to have a resolver that returns only products with a specific `vendorId`, this should work:

```
type Query {
  products($vendorId: Int): [Product]
}


const resolvers = {
  ...
  products: ({ vendorId }) => {
    return store.products.values().filter(product => product.vendor.id === vendorId);
  },
  ...
};
```

Please elaborate if that wasn't the case ;)

Comment: Thanks that was helpful.